# Indent code in Dreamweaver

Tags: dreamweaver

I've searched a lot for this and can't find how to Indent code in dreamweaver...

COMMAND-OPT+] - I've found this on google but it didn't work with me, I'm using a mac book air and to achieve ] I have to do alt+9 ( ] -> alt+9

I just want to indent automatically a bunch of code.. I know dreamweaver has automatic indenting but that just works when I'm writing code, but when I copy piece of code that are not indented like I do, ( I use tabs ), it doesn't indent them. I have to do it manually

Thanks

Comment: What version of dreamweaver? I have CS6 and `option+command+]` works for me on my Mac.

Comment: It's the CS6, the problem is I can't do the ] without using the option key + 9 .... Shift+tab just takes tabs out of my code

Answer (score 0):

I typically use the formatting tool at http://www.freeformatter.com/html-formatter.html#ad-output. If you're using a copied block of code, you could format it with this tool and paste it accordingly into your existing code.  An extra step, but well worth it in my experience.